# Как перевернуть несколько спрайтов по x?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Персонаж раньше состоял из одного спрайта. Теперь он состоит из нескольких спрайтов, как сделать так, чтобы поворачивались все сразу по x?
У меня есть эти строки:

```
    public GameObject[] Player;

        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            Player = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        }
        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            Player = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
        }
```

Выходит ошибка: `Assets\scripts\player\PlayerSpeed.cs(39,22): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]'`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А может быть сразу корневой поворачивать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я пробовал поворачивать через корневой, но ничего не менялось. Если поворачивать их по отдельности - то это работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ответа я не получил, поэтому скажу плохой способ, который занимает много строчек:

```
    public GameObject Body;
    public GameObject Head;

        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            Body = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
            Head = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        }
        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            Body = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
            Head = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
        }
```